# Replace Number that falls Between Two Values (Pandas,Python3)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Simple Question Here:

```
b = 8143.1795845088482
d = 14723.523658084257
```

My Df called final:

```
Words       score
This      90374.98788
is        80559.4495
a         43269.67002
sample    34535.01172
output    Very Low
```

I want to replace all the scores with either 'very low', 'low', 'medium', or 'high' based on whether they fall between quartile ranges.

something like this works:

```
final['score'][final['score'] <= b] = 'Very Low' #This is shown in the example above
```

but when I try to play this immediately after it doesn't work:

```
final['score'][final['score'] >= b] and final['score'][final['score'] <= d] = 'Low'
```

This gives me the error: cannot assign operator.  Anyone know what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your DataFrame's scores were all floats,

```
In [234]: df
Out[234]: 
    Words        score
0    This  90374.98788
1      is  80559.44950
2       a  43269.67002
3  sample  34535.01172
```

then you could use `pd.qcut` to categorize each value by its quartile:

```
In [236]: df['quartile'] = pd.qcut(df['score'], q=4, labels=['very low', 'low', 'medium', 'high'])

In [237]: df
Out[237]: 
    Words        score  quartile
0    This  90374.98788      high
1      is  80559.44950    medium
2       a  43269.67002       low
3  sample  34535.01172  very low
```

DataFrame columns have a dtype. When the values are all floats, then it has a float dtype, which can be very fast for numerical calculations. When the values are a mixture of floats and strings then the dtype is `object`, which mean each value is a Python object. While this gives the values a lot of flexibility, it is also very slow since every operation ultimately resorts back to calling a Python function instead of a NumPy/Panda C/Fortran/Cython function. Thus you should try to avoid mixing floats and strings in a single column.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you must use the bitwise (e.g. `&`, `|` instead of `and` , `or`) operators as you are comparing arrays and therefore all the values and not a single value (it becomes ambiguoous to compare arrays like this plus you cannot override the global `and` operator to behave like you want), secondly you must use parentheses around multiple conditions due to operator precendence.

Finally you are performing [chain indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) which may or may not work and will raise a warning, to set your column value use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing-loc-iloc-and-ix) like this:

```
In [4]:

b = 25 
d = 50
final.loc[(final['score'] >= b) & (final['score'] <= d), 'score'] = 'Low'
final
Out[4]:
  Words score
0  This    10
1    is   Low
2   for   Low
3   You   704
```

Comment: Hi Ed, this throws the following error: ValueError: Arrays were different lengths: 58 vs 1

Comment: You'll have to edit valid input data and your code for me to  reproduce your error. On your data you posted my code works fine as you can see.

Comment: updated, I haven't the slightest why this error is being thrown -- OP updated

Comment: it's being caused by the first replace line and the inclusion of the values 'Very Low' in the final df...just not sure how to get around this

Comment: @user3682157 your problem here is that once you overwrite the value for the first quartile you effectively change the dtype to be a mixture of strings and ints/floats. The comparison now no longer works, it would be better to assign the string representations to a new column like unutbu suggests